# Date is not showing in edit section in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5

my date field is not showing when I try to edit my form. Every field including the time section is showing but the date field is showing as default format. I have checked the database table. The data for the date field is stored there but in edit form it's not showing.

Here is my model

```
namespace LeaveManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class CompensatoryLeave
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Designation Designation { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Compensatory Leave Hours")]
        public decimal CompensatoryLeaveHours { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Compensatory Leave Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime CompensatoryLeaveDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Starting Hour")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:H:mm}")]
        public DateTime From { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ending Hour")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:H:mm}")]
        public DateTime To { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Total Compensatory Leave Hours")]
        public decimal TotalHours { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Reason Of Leave")]
        public string ReasonOfLeave { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: show your UI codes as well.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/35VsABXeGu8vMiHteiYznsj

Comment: which property is not showing?

Comment: compensatoryLeaveDate

and the Date field on the top